# how to properly register Protobuf schema with Schema Registry / Kafka-Rest

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, kafka-rest

I am trying to post a Protobuf schema to the Schema Registry using kafka-rest interface:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.protobuf.v2+json" \
   -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
   --data '{"value_schema": "syntax=\"proto3\"; message User { string name = 1; }", "records": [{"value": {"name": "testUser"}}]}' \
   "http://localhost:8082/topics/protobuftest"
```

I am getting this error:

```
{"error_code":415,"message":"HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"}
```

Question: what is the proper way to indicate the media type for this to work?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send it in a JSON envelope, since it is not an avro schema.

```
$ curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/json" 
http://localhost:8081/subjects/protobuf/versions 
-d "{\"schemaType\": \"PROTOBUF\", \"schema\": \"syntax = \\\"proto3\\\";message test { int32 id = 1; }\"}"
```